# How to send data from Xcode 8 into PHP MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, swift, xcode8

I would like to ask on how to post the data from Xcode 8 into PHP MySQL database. Right now I have **textField username** and **register button** to triggered the function post.

Here's my code so far.

**registerVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
class RegisterVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var usernametxt: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func register_click(_ sender: Any) {

        if usernametxt.text!.isEmpty{
            usernametxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])
        }

        else{
            // Insert data into database  
        }
    }
}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
    global $connect;  
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $username       = $_POST['username'];
        $insert         = "INSERT INTO table (username)
                                     VALUES  ('$username')";
        $run            = mysqli_query($connect,$insert);

        $response = array();
        $response["success"] = true; 
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `else` add `sendData(usernametxt.text)` 
and add below function in your VC file

```
func sendData(username : String) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"http://YOUR_WEBPAGE_ADDRESS")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "name="+username
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                               
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }  
    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
   }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: "let task" has an error. it says that initialization of immutable value 'task' was never used

Comment: add `task.resume()` at end

Comment: i think its working since no error appear when i try to build it. but en error "ssl cert handshake failure" . do you have any solution for this issue ? thanks . ..

Comment: Error "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Comment: As per Apple latest policies(ATS) you need to have HTTPS sites to request from App, So get SSL certificate for your website

Comment: I already have HTTPS domain. How to allow the connection ? i'm testing apps from x code into my HTTPS domain right now. .

Comment: check the URL with a browser to find about more about the issue.

Comment: i'm using xcode 8.2.1 , i believe this version using swift 3 . . you have updated solution ? cause your code did not work at all . data still cannot be added in mysql database . .

Comment: Firstly try to add data using postman or other rest client, maybe the problem is with server side script